# How to get AMD Radeon HD 7900 woriking with Ubuntu 13.10 inside VMWare?

Tags: 13.10, radeon, vmware, fglrx

After the upgrade of ubuntu to 13.10 the performance of my VM has degreased extremely and I think it is because no proprietary drivers seem to be available. The VM runs on decent system (SSD, 4GB ram for the VM, I5 3570) and has worked fine before the update. No third party drivers are beeing offered through the update system (hui).

I have [tried](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/ATI/fglrx) [several](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) [tutorials](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775) to install the drivers manually but without success. The 7900 is [listed](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/amdcatalyst13-4linreleasenotes.aspx) as a supported card at the AMD drivers page and I have tried both the stable and the beta release however without much success. After the last listed tutorial the system boots to the login screen where it returns after entering the password (with a short black screen inbetween). VMWare Here is my Xorg log (/var/log/Xorg.1.log) at the place where the error occurs:
[image: /var/log/Xorg.1.log:]

I have also tried reinstalling vmware tools but without any change.

The command `lspci -nn | grep VGA` returns `VGA compatible controller [0300]: VMware SVGA II Adapter [15ad:0405]`.

Even [uninstalling](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx) didn't work, so I had to go back to a backup.

So my question is: Is it possible to run the latest catalyst drivers (for the HD 7900) unter Ubuntu 13.10 (inside VMWare)? Should the performance be fine with the open source drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware based virtual machine products emulate a graphics controller, you cannot use HD7900 graphics driver within the vm because the vm has a different graphics controller, you must install drivers for your card on the host os, and install vmware tools in the guest os. If you would like to attach a real graphics controller to a virtual machine you will need to use an alternative software that supports pci-e vm inputs such as Parrallels Workstation Extreme, in which case you need two graphics cards (1 for the host, 1 for the guest).

For more information about connecting pci-e devices to a vm directly read this:
http://kb.parallels.com/en/9427

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I have updated my host GPU drivers and the performance seems to have increased. It was only a minor update from 13.9 to 13.12 and the performance is far from perfect but the cpu load seems to have decreased.